# How do I make a program using 3 overloaded functions (difference in parameters is int, long, float) meanwhile only asking one input entry?

Tags: c++, overloading

I have to write a program where I put in two numbers and the program calculates the average. I want to write my program so that if I input two decimal numbers, the program will call the float function, and if I input two integer numbers it will call the integer function, input two long numbers, it will call long function.

The main problem I am having is choosing the variable type. Because if I use a long type for my variable, but the two numbers input by the user are decimal, then the program calls the long function and the average comes out as a long variable.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
#include <iostream>

int average(int, int);
long average(long, long);
float average(float, float);

int main()
{
        //The variables
        //      The problem with them is that if I use
        //      a type, let's say int, but the input
        //      is a float, then it won't work
         x;
         y;
         averag;

        std::cout << "Here is a number: ";
        std::cin >> x;  
        std::cout << "\nHere is another one: ";
        std::cin >> y;

        //The function in call
        averag = average(x, y);

        std::cout << "\n\nHere is the average: ";
        std::cout << averag;
        return 0;
}

//The definition of the int function
int average(int x, int y)
{
        int x;
        int y;
        int average;
        average = (x + y) / 2;
        return average;
}

// The definition of the short function
short average(short x, short y)
{
        short x;
        short y;
        short average;
        average = (x + y) / 2;
        return average;
}

// The definition of the float function
float average(float x, float y)
{
        float x;
        float y;
        float average;
        average = (x + y) / 2;
        return average;
}

//I think i'm not grasping the scopes in which I can define a variable
//and where I must define the parameters within the functions
```

I think that defining the type variables in each function scope is wrong, but how else am i supposed to define the variables!

How to do that ?

Comment: You seem to be confused about when an overloaded function gets resolved.  The compiler figures out which function to call when your program is compiled, not at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

I would have the user input the type first (e.g. 'Enter F for float, I for integer...' etc) then using that input as a condition, read the input into the appropriate type of variable and call your overloaded `average` function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, defining the variables in the function scope the way you have is wrong. Your parameters are defining the variables, defining them in the function will just define them again. I'm not the most familiar with c++, but I think that will "shadow" the parameter variables, and your calculations will not work.

For the main question, I agree with sje397's answer, have the user input the type of average they want to perform first. If the user enters 5 and 4, the `double` average will be different than the `long` average.

Answer (score 0):

I would input the value as a string and then use successive calls to [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) to infer a type:

```
std::string x,y;
std::cin >> x >> y;
try {
  short averag = average(boost::lexical_cast<short>(x), boost::lexical_cast<short>(y));
  std::cout << averag << "\n";
  return;
} catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast&) {}
try {
  int averag = average(boost::lexical_cast<int>(x), boost::lexical_cast<int>(y));
  std::cout << averag << "\n";
  return;
} catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast&) {}
try {
  float averag = average(boost::lexical_cast<float>(x), boost::lexical_cast<float>(y));
  std::cout << averag << "\n";
  return;
} catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast&) {}

std::cout << "Oops\n";
```

I'd probably not use this form, however. I'd probably factor out the common code into a function template.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the user which calculation he wants to perform. 
Drawbacks:

1. Internals of the program which are of no interest to the user, are exposed (the user wants to calculate the average of two numbers).
2. You cannot trust the user. If your program is robust and doesn't crash (for example if the user types in decimal numbers after choosing the integer calculation), it may produce wrong results

I reccomend to read in the input each time and look if the value is a decimal number, a short integer (less than 9 digits) or a long integer. Then you have to consider a few cases (for example one input is decimal, the other a long integer) and to perform the calcuation. It's quite low-level, but I would it refactor out into a function anyway.